# Запуск программы c++ из bat-файла

Tags: c++, bat

Есть программа. Нужно создать bat, который бы запускал эту программу в количестве 10 штук. В консоли я прописываю mpiexec -n 10 MPI1, мне выводится результат(то есть все работает). Как то же самое запустить через bat?

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    cout << "I'm process # " << rank << ", size = " << size << endl;

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Написать в bat-файле "mpiexec -n 10 MPI1"?

Answer (score 3):

```
for /L %%i in (1, 1, 10) do (
    mpiexec -n 10 MPI1
)
```

Comment: то есть только это прописать в текстовый файл и сохранить его в формате bat?

Comment: @АлексейГросс да

Comment: не работает почему-то

Comment: @АлексейГросс а если через командную строку запустить?

Comment: ну в консоли я как делаю: указываю путь до папки, где находится exe-шник, потом прописываю mpiexec -n 10 MPI1 и все работает

Comment: @АлексейГросс, кодировку проверь.